# display 3 items inside ion-slide

Tags: css, ionic2

I have a list which have 9 to 15 images i am able to put it as a list and on clicking any image it will navigate to its respective page.

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor=" let item of animateItems; let i=index ">
     <ion-row >
            <ion-col width-33 style="padding: 3px; "   (click)="openCategory(item.name)">
                <ion-card style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;    width: calc(100%);">
                    <img src="{{item.image}}"  />
                    <p style="    margin-top: -24px;color: #fff;    text-align: center;    text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #000;">
                        {{item.name}}
                    </p>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
 </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

What happens in the above code is only one image is been displayed could someone help me to display 3 images on one single slide. consider i have 12 images so 3 slides in each slide 4 images should be displayed could someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the length of your array and number of images theres two ways to do this.
But first 2 things:

- You're creating a slide for every image, using `*ngFor` on `ion-slide` will create a new slide for every item in the array.
- I don't know what Ionic version you're using, but on 3.x the `width-x` attribute for `ion-col` is deprecated, use `col-x` instead (like Bootstrap).

### 1

Modify so you can have 3 arrays of four items

```
animateItems1: any[] = [{item: item}, {item: item}, {item: item}, {item: item}];
animateItems2: any[] = [{item: item}, {item: item}, {item: item}, {item: item}];
animateItems3: any[] = [{item: item}, {item: item}, {item: item}, {item: item}];
```

And create a slide for every array

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
     <ion-row>
            <ion-col *ngFor=" let item of animateItems1; let i=index " col-3 style="padding: 3px;" (click)="openCategory(item.name)">
                <ion-card style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;    width: calc(100%);">
                    <img src="{{item.image}}"  />
                    <p style="margin-top: -24px;color: #fff; text-align: center; text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #000;">
                        {{item.name}}
                    </p>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <!-- The same code as above, but for animateItems2, and then another for animateItems3 -->
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Yes i know you'll have to code every slide, but that's a way.

### 2

You can nest `*ngFor`, but then again you'll need to modify your array

```
animateItems: any[] = [{
  0: [{item: item}, {item: item}, {item: item}],
  1: [{item: item}, {item: item}, {item: item}],
  2: [{item: item}, {item: item}, {item: item}]
}]
```

And your HTML

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let item of animateItems: let i = index">
     <ion-row>
            <ion-col*ngFor="let lowerItem of animateItems[i]; let ind = index col-3 style="padding: 3px;" (click)="openCategory(lowerItem.name)">
                <ion-card style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; width: calc(100%);">
                    <img src="{{lowerItem.image}}"  />
                    <p style="margin-top: -24px;color: #fff; text-align: center; text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #000;">
                        {{lowerItem.name}}
                    </p>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
  </ion-slide>
```

Since i don't know the appearance of the page i can't help with CSS and the cols division and everything. But hope this helps :)